# How to take user input into an array and stop after a certain keyword?

Tags: bash

I want to take input from user(at run time) and store into an array until user enter, for example "q".
I'm having problems while taking input. The closest working code I got so far is below:

```
while read inputs
do
array=("${array[@]}" $inputs)
done
echo User1 has:${array[0]}
echo User2 has:${array[1]}
echo User3 has:${array[2]}

Output
User1 has:123
User2 has:asd
User3 has:qw12
```

But the problem with this is I have to hit Ctrl+D (EOF) to tell there are no more input.There are other methods I've tried, most of them are erroneous

```
counter=1
read array;
for i in ${array[@]};do
User$counter=$i
echo User$counter
done
```

**Is there any better way to take array input? Please help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ "$inputs" == "done" ] && break
```

Just add this and type *done* to exit

**Example**

```
while read inputs
do
    [ "$inputs" == "done" ] && break 
    array=("${array[@]}" $inputs)
done
```

Comment: Actually this is what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `read -n 1` like this:

```
printf "Enter your input [ q to stop ]: "    
input=

while read -rn1 ch && [[ $ch != 'q' ]]; do
    input+="$ch"
done
printf "\ninput=[%s]\n" "$input"
```

**Output:**

```
Enter your input [ q to stop ]: asdfghjklq
input=[asdfghjkl]
```

You don't need to press enter or ctrl-D. As soon as `q` is pressed this loop will terminate.

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly. Just made a small change to make it work with my code. Thank you sir!